# I've a piece of Android code, want to test if it really works. how do I?

Tags: android

I've set the alarm to repeat after 1 day. How do I test if this code will really trigger AlarmReceiver event after 1 day. (Obviously, I don't want to wait for 1 day to check if this really works)

I tried changing time on my test device. But it did not trigger the event.

Here's the code:

```
public void showNotificationAtTime(final Context context, final long time, final int REQUEST_CODE, final boolean setRepeating, final long repeatAfter) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);

    if (setRepeating == true && repeatAfter >= 60000) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, repeatAfter, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set the alarm to repeat after a shorter period of time, like 1 minute?

Comment: Yes. that will work at programmer side. Not while QA testing